# using context.drawImage to change video element into canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the users camera as a video element and I am taking out screenshots using

```
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
```

I have used

```
 video{
    object-fit:cover;
 }
```

So that the video takes up the whole video element but when I copy it to the canvas element it appears as if I have not object-fit:cover;

How can I make it so it copies the video element as it is seen to the canvas element?